# CSS Media Query multiple ranges

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a requirement where a CSS rule applies between 2 ranges and then above a breakpoint. For example: I need my background to be green, unless the width is 750-800, 850-900 or 900+.

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
.foo { 
    background: green
}

@media all
  and (
    ((min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 800px)),
    ((min-width: 850px) and (max-width: 900px)),
    (min-width: 950px)
  ) {
    .foo {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/njt1982/c2a0yuLh/

If my browser width were 775px then both criteria are met, aren't they? (I am "all" and I am within the first range).

Is what I want to do even possibe?

### Update

I found a method below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786265/224707
However it involved repeating the "all and" part. Is there any way to "group" parts? eg `x AND (y OR z)`?

Comment: you shouldn't need to repeat the `all` part,  it is implied; the issue is your syntax

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax was incorrect. You were adding another set of `()` to your `@media` rule.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gggr04x9/1/)**

Also, you don't need to explicitly state `all`, the lack a `media-type` define is implied as `all` - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Syntax)

```css
div {
    background: green;
}

@media
    (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 700px),
    (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 800px),
    (min-width: 850px) {
    
    div {
        background: red;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per usual, I spend ages on something only to figure it out moments after asking...

```
.foo { 
    background: green
}

@media all and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 800px),
       all and (min-width: 850px) and (max-width: 900px),
       all and (min-width: 950px) {
    .foo {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/njt1982/zyjnvjpz/